# "Google Play services are updating" message

Tags: google-play-services

Since ~ 27 July, in MapMyRide the map has been blank with a message "Google Play services are updating". GPS works fine in the Google Maps app itself. I thought this was specifically a problem with MMR but today I noticed the same thing in the Meetup app.

I tried uninstalling the updates to Google Play services & rebooting, but this had no effect.

Using Android 4.4.4 on Samsung Galaxy S3 (GT-I9305). Google Play services version 9.4.52 (036-127739847)

Comment: Did the uninstall updates actually uninstall them?

Comment: Try to delete the cache of the mentioned applications from settings, especially Google Play Services.